# Notepad++ replace only specified word in a line

Tags: notepad++

I'm trying to replace a specific word in every line in Notepad++. I've managed to duplicate said line like so:

> cn: Johanna Zimmermann
> cn: Johanna Zimmermann

And in every second line I want to replace *cn* to *displayName*. In Notepad++ I found out how you can mark every second duplicate line with `(cn:.*)\s+\K\1`, now I just need the regex expression to change the second duplicate like this:

> cn: Johanna Zimmermann
> displayName: Johanna Zimmermann

How do I do this? Never used Regex before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try doing the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    cn: (.*)\Rcn: (.*)
Replace: cn: $1\ndisplayName: $2
```

The find captures in `$1` and `$2` the `cn` values from a pair of adjacent lines.  The replacement then uses `displayName` as the label of the second line.

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If both lines should be the same, and you would also like to keep the same amount of spaces in the replacement, you can use 2 capture groups with 2 backreferences.

Find what:

```
(cn:)(.*)\R\1\2
```

Replace with:

```
$1$2\ndisplayName:$2
```

The pattern matches:

- `(cn:)` Capture **group 1**, match `cn:`
- `(.*)` Capture **group 2**, match the rest of the line
- `\R\1\2` Match a newline followed by 2 backreferences to group 1 and group 2

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p0YIry/1)

[image]

Comment: A perfect demo with a screenshot!